# Can someone solve the probability problem in description?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, problem-solving, dice

A and B throw a pair of die alternatively. A wins if he throws $6$ (i.e. his thrown die sum up to $6$) before B throws $7$, and B wins if he throws $7$ before A throws $6$. If first throw is done by A, find the probability that A wins the game?

Edit: Ops! I misunderstood the question in the way that A wins if he throws $6$ and immediately in the next trial, B throws $7$, and similar condition for B to win. Thanks to the answer giver. But still, how to solve it with this alternate interpretation? Thank you and sorry again!

Comment: Also see here: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=g2icCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=a+and+b+throw+dices.+a+wins+if+he+throws+six+before+b+throws+seven&source=bl&ots=cnbgxv50E9&sig=_xuREpYanxkbgbso4BhBKjvpIlY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA2NfanYrRAhWBwI8KHZCJA8MQ6AEIQzAJ#v=onepage&q=a%20and%20b%20throw%20dices.%20a%20wins%20if%20he%20throws%20six%20before%20b%20throws%20seven&f=false

Comment: If I have understood the edit (not clear) you say $A$ needs a $6$ immediately followed by a $7$ to win (and $B$ needs a $7$ followed by a $6$)?  If so, then I'd do it with Markov states.  $S_1$ is the start...no running string, $A's$ turn.  $S_2$ is "no running string, $B's$ turn.  $S_3$ is "it's $B's$ turn and $A$ just rolled a $6$"  and $S_4$ is "it's $A's$ turn and $B$ just rolled a $7$.  Plus states for Win and Loss of course.  Then $S_1$ goes to either $S_2$ (prob. $\frac {31}{36}$) or $S_3$ (prob. $\frac 5{36}$) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Method I (Recursion).  Three things can happen in any given round...$A$ wins, $A$ loses, the game starts over.  Thus the answer, $X$, is given by the recursive formula $$X=\frac 5{36}\times 1+\frac {31}{36}\times \frac 6{36}\times 0 + \left(1-\frac 5{36}-\frac {31}{36}\times \frac 6{36}\right)X\implies \boxed {X=\frac {30}{61}}$$

Method II (Markov states) :  This game has two non-final states:  "$A's$ turn, $B's$ turn"  Denote the probability that $A$ eventually wins given that it's $A's$ turn as $X$, and the probability that $A$ eventually wins given that it's $B's$ turn as $Y$.

Clearly:  $$X=\frac 5{36}\times 1 +\frac {31}{36}\times Y$$  and

$$Y=\frac 6{36}\times 0 +\frac {30}{36}\times X$$

This is easily solved and yields our answer $$\boxed {X=\frac {30}{61}}$$

Method III:  The game will end on some round with probability $1$. On any given round the winner will be $A$ with probability $\frac 5{36}$ and $B$ with probability $\frac {31}{36} \times \frac {6}{36}$.  Thus the eventual winner is $A$ with probability $$\frac {\frac 5{36}}{\frac 5{36}+\frac {31}{36}\times \frac {6}{36}}=\frac {5\times 36}{5\times 36+31\times 6}=\boxed {\frac {30}{61}}$$